# Return value from a modal window with iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, modal-dialog

I have a modal window opened in jquery, in the modal window I open an other webpage with an iframe. In these iframe I have and input text.
I need that when I close the Modal window, it return the value in the inputtext for to modify it.
I think that I could do these with a cookie or with a post value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The code in the iframe is the next

```
var valInput = $("input[name='valReturn']").val();
$("input[name='imageText']",parent.document.body).val(valInput);
parent.closeIFrame();
```

The second line is a reference to parent, and the last line is a call to a method into parent. The code is the next:

```
function closeIFrame(){
$.modal.close();
}
```